# IS command - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

```
seanmac5291@seanmac5291-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ~ is
bash: /home/seanmac5291: Is a directory
seanmac5291@seanmac5291-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ~/Desktop
bash: /home/seanmac5291/Desktop: Is a directory
```

Why am I getting these responses instead of seeing the the directory in command line?

Comment: The question is a bit vague but maybe you're looking for the ls command (LS, both lower case just to be clear).

Comment: @dsSTORM I was also wondering what `is` is?

Comment: That was it. I just started trying to learn different commands in Linux and i misread "LS" as "IS" while reading some tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: @George Udosen it just tells you what something is, i.e. ~/Documents is a directory etc.

Comment: @dsSTORM it does nothing. It's not a command. If you enter a path (in fact, anything with a `/` or that expands to something with a `/` such as `~` or `$HOME`), Bash assumes you want to run the file and runs it if possible. If it's a directory, it tells you so, because you can't run a directory (so, this is an error message). If it doesn't exist, `no such file or directory`. If it's not an executable file, you get a permission error. If it is executable, it will be run, and `is` will be its first argument. Enter `is` by itself - command not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is not `is` but `ls` (lowercase LS).

Type `ls` only to list the contents of your current directory.

If you additionally specify a path as argument, it will show the contents of that one instead, like one of these

```
ls /usr/local
ls ~/Documents
ls ..
```

See `man ls` for more information.

Useful options for `ls` are e.g. `-a` to view all files, including hidden files (with a name starting with `.`) and `-l` for a long and more verbose output format, including stuff like size, owner, permissions and change date.

Comment: Doh. appreciate it!